# RE:FAILED: SemanticException Column name Found in more than One Tables/Subqueries

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

i got a problem with my query while inserting records in new table with full outer join:
before that i have created two tables by names:

1. emp
2. dept

```sql
create table emp (
    id int,
    name string,
    sal int,
    sex string,
    dno int
);

create table dept (
    dno int,
    name string,
    dloc string
);
```

I then created new table where to insert the records:

```sql
create table edinfo (
    id int,
    name string,
    sal int,
    sex string,
    dname string,
    dloc string,
    dno1 int,
    dno2 int
);
```

I've wrote this query to get the data to insert in `edinfo`:

```sql
insert overwrite table edinfo
    select
        id,
        name,
        sal,
        sex,
        dname,
        dloc,
        l.dno,
        r.dno
from emp l
    full outer join dept r on (l.dno = r.dno)
;
```

But I got this error:

FAILED: SemanticException Column name Found in more than One Tables/Subqueries

Can someone tell me what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your query you don't use table alias for the field `name` and it is present in both `emp` and `dept`.
Use `l.name` or `r.name` based on which table you need to get the `name` from.

As you are a new StackOverflow user, let me suggest you to use code blocks to write table definitions and queries. I'll try to edit your post to let you see how your question should have been written.

Comment: #Answered #thanks you Ma3x and please let me know how to use code blocks and how to question on stackoverflow

Comment: @jd1202, if my answer has solved your question, please mark it as "accepted" :) To add code blocks to questions and answers, just put three back-quotes ("```") before and after the code block. After the first three back-quotes you can also specify the language of the code block, to apply the correct syntax highlighting